# ReactJs - Can I load Common js libraries in react project separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project which has 2 separate Reactjs projects. Both react projects are created by **React create app** and are using JSX syntax. My command is `npm run build`.

I was wondering if there is a way to optimise them such that React core/basic **js library** is loaded separately and is common in both projects to leverage cache. Both have React, axios, Redux, bootstrap libraries.

Lets say if I load these scripts in header

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But I guess same scripts will be included when `npm run build` creates a build file.

One project has **.js** file of size **328KB** and another has of **800KB** and some optimisation can really help me.

Please advise. 
Thanks

*P.S. To anyone wondering why they are two separate projects, they were two totally separate tools offered to customers/users and i didn't want to mix them in same project to increase complexity unnecessarily.*

Answer (score 0):

Reject your create-react-app project and modify webpack config.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

try this.

Comment: May be you mean `Eject` ?

Comment: @Sallu By default, all settings are hidden in create-react-app. Running "npm run eject" will show hidden settings. However, in the case of "eject", it is not possible to return to "eject".

Comment: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject